# Why does XML::LibXML::Document's toString() give me "SCALAR(...)" instead of an XML string?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

Here is a code sample that reproduces the behaviour I wonder about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $myXMLdocument = XML::LibXML::Document->new();

my $myXML = $myXMLdocument->createElement("myXML");
$myXMLdocument->addChild($myXML);

my $element = $myXMLdocument->createElement("element");
$myXML->addChild($element);

my $node = $myXMLdocument->createElement("node");
$element->addNewChild('', $node);
$node->addNewChild('', $myXMLdocument->createAttribute( "key" => "value"));

print "$myXMLdocument->toString(2)\n";
```

The output :

```
XML::LibXML::Document=SCALAR(0x8f5a6f8)->toString(2)
```

I understand that this is some sort of handle for the document structure passed around by [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML).

Now why doesn't `toString` serialize it to human readable XML?

I may be extremely naïve about `XML::LibXML`; this is my first time using it instead of spewing out random XML with Bash's echo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a basic Perl problem and nothing special to do with `XML::LibXML`. Perl expands simple variables inside quoted strings but not function calls. If you change your code to

```
print $myXMLdocument->toString(2), "\n";
```

then you will get the result you need.

---

**Update**

You are using the module slightly wrongly. These lines

```
my $node = $myXMLdocument->createElement("node");
$element->addNewChild('', $node);
$node->addNewChild('', $myXMLdocument->createAttribute( "key" => "value"));
```

create a new element `$node` and then call `addNewChild` to add it to `$element`. But `addNewChild` takes a tag name as its second parameter so Perl is stringifying the `$node` object to give the strange tag name that you see. Instead you need

```
my $node = $myXMLdocument->createElement('node');
$element->addChild($node);
$node->addChild($myXMLdocument->createAttribute(key => 'value'));
```

or you could stick with `addNewChild` and write

```
my $node = $element->addNewChild('', 'node');
$node->setAttribute(key => 'value');
```

---

**Update**

You might want to consider [`XML::API`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aAPI) which is my preferred module for *writing* XML. It allows for concise code, and because it builds a proper XML data tree instead of just appending text to a buffer it is a lot more subtle than it may appear. For more complex structures there is a `_goto` method that allows you to go back to nodes in the tree and add more data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::API;

my $xml = XML::API->new;
$xml->myXML_open;
$xml->element_open;
$xml->node({ key => 'value' });
$xml->element_close;
$xml->myXML_close;

print $xml;
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<myXML>
  <element>
    <node key="value" />
  </element>
</myXML>
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll read about quoting, variable & function expansion... But we are only halfway to the solution : I now get the following :

`<?xml version="1.0"?><myXML><element>    <XML::LibXML::Element=SCALAR(0xa127580)/></element></myXML>`

This is actually what I was having from my actual script : good outer XML but unexpanded stuff inside... Another thing about expansion that I am missing ?

Comment: The problem now is that you are calling the module methods incorrectly. See the update to my answer.

Comment: I suspected that I was confused between addChild and addNewChild but I could not put my finger on it... So this was a XML::LibXML problem after all. I am working on an Openstreetmap data import and this removed one of the last remaining hurdles. So thank you !

Comment: The XML I'm producing is the [osmChange format](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OsmChange) which is produced in an utterly linear way - so the simplicity of XML:API looks good to me and I'll take advantage of my still malleable mind to give it a try before I get too used to XML::LibXML - thank you for the suggestion. For reading the XML output of Openstreetmap's Overpass API I'm using xpath expressions and they work fine. I'm excited about moving forward !